# writing xml file to string and then inserting into oracle db groovy

Tags: xml, oracle, groovy

Hi I have and xml file called test.xml with the following contents

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <ns:AccountQueryPage_Output xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/ecbs/account/">
  <ListOfAccount xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/Account/Data" lastpage="true">
  <Account>
  <Id>CCC-TEST01</Id> 
  <AccountName>John Smith Pty Ltd</AccountName> 
  </Account>
  </ListOfAccount>
  </ns:AccountQueryPage_Output>
```

I need to load the contents into an oracle table called SCOTT.RESP using groovy

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

String fileContents = new File('C:\\Documents\\test.xml').getText('UTF-8')
println fileContents

sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhpst:1521/orcl.com", "SCOTT", "Password","oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource")
sql.execute("""INSERT INTO SCOTT.RESP VALUES(fileContents)""")
```

I get the error

ORA-00984: column not allowed here

(Subtract 17 from the error line number to account for the standard imports)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Do u know why I get this error?

Regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the oracle tech forum

https://community.oracle.com/message/10271899

thank you